# How to find Gaussian curvature here?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

> $\textbf{Problem}$ Let $M=\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the standard coordinates $(x,y)$. Consider the following Riemannian metric on $M$:
>   $$dx^{2}+2\cos(\alpha(x,y))dxdy+dy^{2},$$
>   where $\alpha$ is a smooth function on $M$ such that $\alpha(x,y)\neq\pi k,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}.$
>
> (a) Prove that the vector fields
>   $$e_{1}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\quad e_{2}=\frac{1}{\sin(\alpha(x,y))}\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}-\cos(\alpha(x,y))\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg)$$
>   constitute an orthonormal frame with respect to this Riemannian metric.
>
> (b) Find the dual coframe to the frame $(e_{1},e_{2})$.
>
> (c) Prove that the Gaussian curvature of this Riemannian metric is equal to $-\frac{\alpha_{xy}}{\sin\alpha}$.

I am having trouble with (c). I think the dual coframes are given by
$$e_{1}^{*}=dx+\cos(\alpha(x,y))dy,\quad e_{2}^{*}=\sin(\alpha(x,y))dy.$$
I tried to use the equation
$$d\omega_{12}=-Ke_{1}^{*}\wedge e_{2}^{*}$$
where 
$$0=de_{1}=\omega_{11}e_{1}+\omega_{12}e_{2}$$
and so, $\omega_{11}=\omega_{12}=0$.

But since $$e_{1}^{*}\wedge e_{2}^{*}=\sin(\alpha(x,y))dx\wedge dy,$$
it looks like $K=0$. What did I do wrong?

$\large\textbf{The following was added to the original question following levap's answer.}$

We have $$\omega_{12}=\langle\nabla_{e_{1}}e_{1},e_{2}\rangle e^{1}+\langle\nabla_{e_{2}}e_{1},e_{2}\rangle e^{2}$$
and
$$\nabla_{e_{1}}e_{1}=\Gamma_{11}^{1}e_{1}+\Gamma_{11}^{2}e_{2},\quad\nabla_{e_{2}}e_{1}=\Gamma_{12}^{1}e_{1}+\Gamma_{12}^{2}e_{2}.$$
We have
$$\begin{gather*}\Gamma_{11}^{1}=\frac{1}{2}g^{11}\bigg(\frac{\partial g_{11}}{\partial x^{1}}+\frac{\partial g_{11}}{\partial x^{1}}-\frac{\partial g_{11}}{\partial x^{1}}\bigg)+\frac{1}{2}g^{12}\bigg(\frac{\partial g_{12}}{\partial x^{1}}+\frac{\partial g_{21}}{\partial x^{1}}-\frac{\partial g_{11}}{\partial x^{2}}\bigg)\\
\Gamma_{11}^{2}=\frac{1}{2}g^{21}\bigg(\frac{\partial g_{11}}{\partial x^{1}}+\frac{\partial g_{11}}{\partial x^{1}}-\frac{\partial g_{11}}{\partial x^{1}}\bigg)+\frac{1}{2}g^{22}\bigg(\frac{\partial g_{12}}{\partial x^{1}}+\frac{\partial g_{21}}{\partial x^{1}}-\frac{\partial g_{11}}{\partial x^{2}}\bigg)\\
\Gamma_{12}^{1}=\frac{1}{2}g^{11}\bigg(\frac{\partial g_{11}}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial g_{12}}{\partial x^{1}}-\frac{\partial g_{12}}{\partial x^{1}}\bigg)+\frac{1}{2}g^{12}\bigg(\frac{\partial g_{12}}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial g_{22}}{\partial x^{1}}-\frac{\partial g_{12}}{\partial x^{2}}\bigg)\\
\Gamma_{12}^{2}=\frac{1}{2}g^{21}\bigg(\frac{\partial g_{11}}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial g_{12}}{\partial x^{1}}-\frac{\partial g_{12}}{\partial x^{1}}\bigg)+\frac{1}{2}g^{22}\bigg(\frac{\partial g_{12}}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial g_{22}}{\partial x^{1}}-\frac{\partial g_{12}}{\partial x^{2}}\bigg)\end{gather*}$$
and
$$g=\begin{pmatrix}1&\cos(\alpha(x,y))\\
\cos(\alpha(x,y))&1\end{pmatrix},\quad g^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{1-\cos^{2}(\alpha(x,y))}&\frac{-\cos(\alpha(x,y))}{1-\cos^{2}(\alpha(x,y))}\\\frac{-\cos(\alpha(x,y))}{1-\cos^{2}(\alpha(x,y))}&\frac{1}{1-\cos^{2}(\alpha(x,y))}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The Christoffel symbols turn out to be
$$\Gamma_{11}^{1}=\frac{\cos(\alpha(x,y))\alpha_{x}}{\sin(\alpha(x,y))},\quad\Gamma_{11}^{2}=\frac{-\alpha_{x}}{\sin(\alpha(x,y))},\quad\Gamma_{12}^{1}=0,\quad\Gamma_{12}^{2}=0.$$
So I got $$\nabla_{e_{1}}e_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}\bigg(\frac{\cos(\alpha(x,y))}{\sin(\alpha(x,y))}+\frac{\cos(\alpha(x,y))}{\sin^{2}(\alpha(x,y))}\bigg)\alpha_{x}\\\frac{-\alpha_{x}}{\sin^{2}(\alpha(x,y))}\end{pmatrix},\quad\nabla_{e_{2}}e_{1}=0$$
and
$\displaystyle\omega_{12}=\bigg\langle\begin{pmatrix}\bigg(\frac{\cos(\alpha(x,y))}{\sin(\alpha(x,y))}+\frac{\cos(\alpha(x,y))}{\sin^{2}(\alpha(x,y))}\bigg)\alpha_{x}\\\frac{-\alpha_{x}}{\sin^{2}(\alpha(x,y))}\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}\frac{-\cos(\alpha(x,y))}{\sin(\alpha(x,y))}\\\frac{1}{\sin(\alpha(x,y))}\end{pmatrix}\bigg\rangle(dx+\cos(\alpha(x,y))dy)=\frac{-\alpha_{x}}{\sin(\alpha)}dx-\frac{\alpha_{x}\cos(\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)}dy.$

By taking exterior derivative, I got
$$d\omega_{12}=\frac{1}{\sin^{2}(\alpha)}\bigg(\alpha_{xy}\sin(\alpha)-\alpha_{x}\alpha_{y}\cos(\alpha)-\alpha_{xx}\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)+\alpha_{x}^{2}\sin^{2}(\alpha)-\alpha_{x}^{2}\cos^{2}(\alpha)\bigg)dx\wedge dy$$
but $Ke^{1}\wedge e^{2}=K\sin(\alpha)dx\wedge dy$, so I don't get $\displaystyle K=\frac{-\alpha_{xy}}{\sin\alpha}$. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Maybe I had to introduce an ambient space and extend the frame $e_{1},e_{2}$ to $e_{1},e_{2},e_{3}$ by say, extending the Riemannian metric to $dx^{2}+2\cos(\alpha(x,y))dxdy+dy^{2}+dz^{2}$? I'm trying to check this but the calculation is quite cumbersome.

Comment: The above didn't give the wanted answer neither. But it seems what went wrong was, because the frame is not holonomic, $\nabla_{e_{i}}e_{j}=\Gamma_{ij}^{k}e_{k}$ was not right.

Comment: I found this formula $K=-\frac{1}{E}\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\Gamma_{12}^{2}-\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\Gamma_{11}^{2}+\Gamma_{12}^{1}\Gamma_{11}^{2}-\Gamma_{11}^{1}\Gamma_{12}^{2}+\Gamma_{12}^{2}\Gamma_{12}^{2}-\Gamma_{11}^{2}\Gamma_{22}^{2}\bigg)$ and this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also keep everything in forms and use the Cartan structural equations (so you don't have to compute the Christoffel symbols). The Cartan Structural equations are:

$de_1^*=\omega_1^2\wedge e_2^*$

$de_2^*=-\omega_1^2\wedge e_1^*$

which imply $\omega_1^2=-\alpha_x dx$.

Then from $d\omega_1^2=-K e_1^*\wedge e_2^*$ you have:

$\alpha_{xy}=-K \sin(\alpha)$ which is what you want.

EDIT: some details:

Write $\omega_1^2=fdx+gdy$. The structural equations are

$-\sin(\alpha)\alpha_x dx\wedge dy=de_1^*=\omega_1^2\wedge e_2^*=f \sin\alpha dx\wedge dy$. Hence $f=-\alpha_x$.

The second equation is:

$\cos(\alpha)\alpha_x dx\wedge dy=de_2^*=-\omega_1^2\wedge \omega_1=(-f\cos(\alpha)-g)dx\wedge dy$, hence $g=0$ and $$\omega_1^2=-\alpha_xdx.$$

Finally $\alpha_{xy} dx\wedge dy=d\omega_1^2=-Ke_1^*\wedge e_2^*=-K\sin\alpha dx\wedge dy$ gives $K$.

Answer (score 0):

You use the same symbol $d$ twice but they mean different things! The expression $d \omega_{12}$ is the exterior derivative of $\omega_{12}$ but $d e_1$ should be $\nabla e_1$ where $\nabla$ is the covariant derivative induced by the Riemannian metric. In any case, even if you thought that $d e_1$ is the regular derivative, I don't understand why $d e_1$ should be zero. Also, I think that you should get $+K$ and not $-K$ with standard conventions.

Allow me to use both upper/lower indices and the Einstein summation convention. The connection $1$-forms $\omega^{i}_j$ are defined by the equation

$$ \nabla_{X} e_i = \omega_i^j(X) e_j $$

where $\nabla$ is the **covariant derivative**. Then $d\omega^2_1 = K \, dA = K \, e^1 \wedge e^2$ where $(e^1,e^2)$ is the dual basis to $(e_1,e_2)$. Thus, you need to compute

$$ \left< \nabla_{e_1} e_1, e_2 \right>, \left< \nabla_{e_2} e_1, e_2 \right>, $$

set

$$ \omega^2_1 = \left< \nabla_{e_1} e_1, e_2 \right> e^1 + \left< \nabla_{e_2} e_1, e_2 \right> e^2 $$

and calculate $d\omega_1^2$.